# C# Convert object to Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, types, precision

I'm trying to convert an object with the value `0.39999999999999997` to a decimal variable without losing the precision.

```
object d = 0.39999999999999997;
```

I've tried the following methods.

```
decimal val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(d); // val1 = 0.4
object val2 = Convert.ChangeType(d, Type.GetType("System.Decimal")); // val2 = 0.4
decimal val3 = decimal.Parse(d.ToString()); // val3 = 0.4
decimal val4 = (Decimal) d; // val4 = 0.4
```

I know the this is not a problem with the decimal data type not being able to store this value as illustrated below.

```
decimal val5 = 0.39999999999999997m; // val5 = 0.39999999999999997;
```

How do I convert this object to decimal without losing the precision?

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 if that matters.

Comment: not very sure you can guarantee persistant precision between boxing/unboxing and different floating types conversion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is the code you looking for:

```
object d = 0.39999999999999997;
//Unbox value
double doubleVal = (double)d;

//Convert to string. R format specifier gives a string that can round-trip to an identical number.  
//Without R ToString() result would be doubleAsString = "0.4"
string doubleAsString = doubleVal.ToString("R"); 

//Now that you have doubleAsString = "0.39999999999999997" parse it!
decimal decimalVal = decimal.Parse(doubleAsString);
```

Comment: Perfect. Although I'm concerned using doubles will affect the data accuracy, this seems like the best option so far. Thanks.

Comment: Well in this case I agree with V4Vendettas comment: `I am afraid then it won't be possible since object holds a reference to the value and in your case unless the reference is of decimal you can't actually get that precision`

Answer (score 6):

For this to work you will need to assign it similarly

```
object d = 0.39999999999999997M;
```

There is no way for the object to maintain the precision unless you force it to. (If this is not the actual code, you will need to show as how its assigned)

Only then would something like this would work `decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(d);`

Comment: Because of the way this variable is initialized (the actual value is stored in a database) I have no way of knowing when it'll be a decimal value.

Comment: If you are anyway going to use decimal why not get the database value and convert it to decimal, what is the issue in that ?

Comment: Let me clarify. This is in a generic method that accepts objects. And I can't change the method signature.

Comment: I am afraid then it won't be possible since object holds a reference to the value and in your case unless the reference is of decimal you can't actually get that precision, it would never be able to unbox to a decimal because it was never boxed as one.

Answer (score 1):

As you are reading data from database(as you noted in one of the comments, IMO you should have added that in your question) I think it's a terrible idea to allow converting to double and back while reading from database, because you will lose precision [likely it's stored as fixed point or in a number system that can represent decimals].
I think that you must put some effort to read the stored values directly as decimals(edit your schema or something like that), or if it's not possible, then read them as strings, and use Decimal.Parse() to get actual values.

Actually your number 0.39999999999999997 has 17 decimal places hence it can't be stored as double safely.

P.S. There's [a great article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) regarding .net Doubles and rounding written by Jon Skeet.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea to convert to a double and back again. Unfortunately that's the only option I have right now because of the application architecture. Going forward, I think I'm going to go with reading the values as strings and then convert it to Decimal. 

And thanks for that article. It was a great read. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string val = "0.39999999999999997");
decimal d = decimal.Parse(val,
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);//0.39999999999999997
```

Comment: `object d = 0.39999999999999997;
double decim = double.Parse(d.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint); //decim = 0.4`

Comment: @Chathura: it is a typo. I mean `decima.Parse` I tested it and the result as expected.

Comment: Hey where did the string come into picture ?

Comment: Whoops. Jumped the gun too quickly it seems. 'd.ToString()' turns it back to 0.4

Comment: @Chathura: I tested it now and it does not turn back to `0.4`. here is my test: `
    string val = "0.39999999999999997";

    decimal d = decimal.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);/*0.39999999999999997*/

    string s = d.ToString();/*0.39999999999999997*/`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the initial variable is not a string but an object. When using `object.ToString()` it converts to `0.4`

Answer (score 0):

`Decimal d = new Decimal(d);`

if d is a double, then according to the documentation [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9dyd10.aspx) this should keep the precision.

> This constructor rounds value to 15 significant digits using rounding to nearest. This is done even if the number has more than 15 digits and the less significant digits are zero.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can't pass an object into the Decimal() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.80).aspx it's written "Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double"
And this code

```
object o = 0.39999999999999997;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```

shows up `System.Double`

while this one

```
object o = 0.39999999999999997m;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```

shows up `System.Decimal`
So you're just losing your precision without the suffix m.

Comment: The Decimal type is necessary because of the way Double stores it's value, it doesn't store the exact value I enter. For instance 12.03 will be stored as 12.029999999999999 etc.

Answer (score 0):

object d =   0.399999999999999999999999997M;
would work you.

Comment: Not an option. The actual value is retrieved from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously all you have to do is something like this...

```
object d = 0.39999999999999997; 
decimal result;
decimal.TryParse(d.ToString(), out result);
return result;
```