# Why does Convert.ToDecimal(Double) round to 15 significant figures?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I have a `double` with 17 digits after the decimal point, i.e.:

```
double myDouble = 0.12345678901234567;
```

If I convert this to a `decimal` like this:

```
decimal myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(myDouble);
```

then the value of `myDecimal` is rounded, as per the `Convert.ToDecimal` documentation, to 15 digits (i.e. `0.0123456789012345`). My question is, why is this rounding performed?

I understand that if my original number could be accurately represented in base 10 and I was trying to store it as a `double`, then we could only have confidence in the first 15 digits. The final two digits would be subject to rounding error. But, that's a base 10 biased point of view. My number may be more accurately represented by a `double` and I wish to convert it to `decimal` while preserving as much accuracy as possible.

Shouldn't `Convert.ToDecimal` aim to minimise the difference between `myDouble` and `(double)Convert.ToDecimal(myDouble)`?

Comment: Perhaps for consistency with `double.ToString`+`decimal.Parse`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840681/c-sharp-convert-object-to-decimal if you are interested in creating a "round-tripable" decimal value.

Comment: You are making a measurement where accuracy to one part in **a quadrillion** is relevant?  Are you running the Large Hadron Collider here? This is a quantity so small as to not warrant stressing out about. The error bar on whatever measurement you are representing in this double is likely to be literally millions of times larger than the rounding error.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm getting a max and min from an SDK behind a C interface (hence ``double``). My system stores these internally as ``decimal``s. When I try to set these values in the SDK they need to be within the max-min range. I'm not stressing out about the accuracy, but that doesn't stop the SDK from returning out of range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation of Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> A Double value has up to **15 decimal digits of precision**, although a
>   maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally

So, as the double value itself has a maximum of 15 decimal places, converting it to Decimal will result in a Decimal value with 15 significant figures.

Comment: Different values of `double` have differing numbers of significant digits when rendered in decimal form, depending upon whether they are just over or just under a power of ten, and just over or just under a power of two.  Values in the range 1000-1023.9, for example, are separated by 1.137E-12, while values in the range 8192 to 9999.9 are separated by 1.819E-11; there is thus more than a decimal digit's worth of difference in the relative precisions of values in those ranges even though they have (in decimal) the same order of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of the rounding guarantees that conversion of any `Decimal` which has at most fifteen significant figures to `double` and back to `Decimal` will yield the original value unchanged.  If values were rounded to sixteen figures rather than fifteen, such a guarantee would not only fail to hold for number with sixteen figures, but it *wouldn't even hold for much shorter values*.  For example, the closest `Double` value to 9000.04 is approximately 9000.040000000000873115; rounding that to sixteen figures would yield 9000.040000000001.

The choice of rounding one should use depends upon whether regards the best `Decimal` value of `double` value 9000.04 as being 9000.04m, 9000.040000000001m, 9000.0400000000008731m, or perhaps something else.  Microsoft probably decided that any representation other than 9000.04m would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The following is from the documentation of the method in question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0(v=vs.110).aspx

"The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.

Comment: That's a tautology. It rounds because it's specified to round. Doesn't really answer the *why*.

Comment: I think OP is interested in the reason behind this instead.

Comment: SO is weird. Sometimes, the only answer deemed acceptable by The Crowd is a simple "because the specs say so" (which not incorrect, but useless as an answer), other times they demand a plausible reason behind it.

Comment: That is not the spec though, it is documentation. Documentation generally describes what it does, not what the spec says it should do.

Comment: Team, this isn't answerable unless you talked to the designers of the language. This is the only acceptable answer. It works like this ***because it does.***

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: While it is possible that the team decided to implement the behavior they did because their astrologer told them to, I suspect their decision probably has more to do with the fact that the value of a `double` like 9999.04 is closer to 9000.040000000001m than to 9000.04m.  If one wants `double` values which are supposed to represent power-of-ten fractions to appear as the fractions they are supposed to represent, rounding to fifteen digits will make that happen; rounding to sixteen won't.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: One could add logic that would say that the closest `double` value to every decimal fraction with fifteen or fewer significant figures should be rounded to fifteen digits, with other double values rounding differently, but that would introduce non-linearities in the conversion which would likely be more harmful than rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Every terminating binary fraction is exactly representable as a decimal fraction, so the minimum possible difference for a finite number is always 0. The IEEE 754 64-bit representation of your number is exactly equal to 0.1234567890123456634920984242853592149913311004638671875

Every conversion from binary floating point to decimal or decimal string must embody some decision about rounding. In theory, they could preserve all the digits, but that would result in some very long outputs with most of the digits having little meaning.

One option, used in Java's Double.toString, is to stop at the shortest decimal representation that would convert back to the original double.

Most set some fairly arbitrary limit. 15 significant digits preserves most meaningful digits.

Comment: The limit is not arbitrary.  The value of (double)8.3 is roughly 8.300000000000000711, which, rounded to 16 significant figures, would be 8.300000000000001.  It might have been possible to say that a double value should round to 16 decimal figures except when a shorter decimal representation would suffice to uniquely identify it, but that would have created some non-uniformities in the worst-case rounding error.  Better might have been to say that values whose most-significant digit is 0-3 will be rounded to the nearest 16-places value...

Comment: ...and those whose most significant digit is 4-7 will be rounded to the nearest even 16-places value.  That would have meant that instead of rounding error going up tenfold between 9.999... and 10.0, it would double between 3.9999... and 4.000, and only go up fivefold between 9.999... and 10.0.