# Type casting issue

Tags: c#

While parsing the string to double we are facing a issue. we need to convert 18 digit string(<123,456,789,012>.<123456>) to double. It returns only 5 digits after the decimal. When we tried to reducing the no of digits, it worked fine. We have attached the screenshot with three different scenarios. Variable 'S' is the input and retValue is the output value.

Kindly help us in converting 123,456,789,012.123456 to 123456789012.123456

```
string s = "123,456,789,012.123456"; 
double retVal; 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Curr‌​ent.Session["culture‌​"].ToString()); 
retVal = double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Any, cInfo);
```

[Issue screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYod.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried? ;)
Ok, it's in your screenshot. Why not adding it as code in your question? Would be easier for all of us.

Comment: It might be possible that the value to parse cannot be exactly represented in the `double` type.

Comment: we have added it in the Issue screen shot

Comment: `Decimal.Parse`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A screenshot isn't code that can be tried. Post the code and what you expected. Although the string you posted *CAN'T* be represented as a double without losing precision. Use `decimal` instead

Comment: double has only up to 15 significant digits precision so use decimal instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Convert.ToDecimal(Double) round to 15 significant figures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495306/why-does-convert-todecimaldouble-round-to-15-significant-figures)

Answer (score 6):

A `double` has a precision of up to 15 digits, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

You should use [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Decimal.Parse(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) that has [28-29 significant digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/364x0z75.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You are running into a precision issue that is inherent to all floating point data types like `double`. If you need more exact precision, you should be using `decimal` instead:

```
string s = "987,654,321.123456";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s);
```

See it in action: https://repl.it/Gtoy/0

**EDIT:** As Panagiotis Kanavos points out, `decimal` isn't perfect either. It uses 128 bits as opposed to `double`'s 64. However, where `double` uses its bits to represent larger numbers, `decimal` uses it to represent smaller numbers with much greater accuracy.

Comment: decimal isn't exact, is a 128-bit floating point number with reduced range and higher precision than the other types